# Dwellings of a cryptic nature

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

[Grid in plaintext](https://pastebin.com/mXTtq0wf)

**Across**
1. Oakley, California finally resettled nine (5)
4. Stupor produced by rotten nectar (6)
9. After revolutionary conflict, conceal leather material (7)
10. Ugly leaders and a North African native (7)
11. 2/18 down native vandalized Wiki (4)
13. Wife of Jacob Latimore, extremely happy, starts looking back (4)
14. Auditor's fear: Ruthless judge (5)
15. Part of the foot to enlarge at first (3)
16. In other words, navigate back following America's eastern coast (5)
17. City in Brazil's north is against a chess champion (5)
19. Ruin one criminal assembly (7)
22. I care about a woman (5)
23. I wander about, back to 2/18 down native (5)
24. Filmmaker Michael's loose-fitting pair of leggings taken off (3)
26. Genuine jungle cat turned, right to left (5)
27. Mexican city gal abandons ship (4)
28. A nearly 26 across region (4)
30. Old ones prepared ramen, maybe (7)
31. Group of three in IT engaged in attempt (7)
33. Thank you, small fellow sailor who reached 2/18 down (6)
34. Talk show host in Montreal – she's followed by 2/18 down's #1 (5)

**Down**
1. Mountain in Australia or a 11 across? (6)
2/18. Three points above European island country (3,7)
3. Liv Tyler's fourth backup is terrible (4)
4. Dwelling made of the last pieces of light sabre (a sword) (6)
5. Arab extremists seen in front of hotel in shaken-up Dubai Emirate (3,5)
6. White wine and fish with mob boss? Nope (10)
7. Man of action's rave turned wild (10)
8. As an A.I., delay cutting areas in a sarcastic way (7)
12. Admiral hosted in dwelling tonight (10)
13. Drop luggage off at first to go on Swiss plane, finally (4)
15. Italian city mostly opposing Ms. Fitzgerald's dance music (10)
18. *(See 2 down)*
20. Stereotypical American flexed a muscle, embracing 2/18 down leader (5,3)
21. Country of O'Brian, for one (4)
24. Cry about time running to city (6)
25. Landform around almost anyone (6)
29. "The Rock" Johnson, finally with even figures (4)
32. Not feeling well? Remove lid from medicine container (3)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

I still don't quite understand two things:

> how exactly 13A works, and what "opposing" is doing in 15D.

Comment: I can't explain $15$D but for $13$A "starts" is trying to tell you to take the first two letters of "happy".  I don't think that's a fair use of "starts" myself, but everyone's slightly different in their cluing :)

Comment: @postmortes Ah, I see now -- that interpretation of "starts" is pretty common, and I even considered it, but missed how the rest would work.

Comment: Nice job once again! For "opposing" I was thinking of "located in front of", as in a building opposing another? It doesn't seem like a great fit for that purpose in retrospect, though...

Comment: l stiII can't see those lmgur things.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat That's still a problem you will have to deal with yourself, because i.stack.imgur.com is *the* canonical way to share images on Stack Exchange. We can't switch the formats of all questions and answers to accommodate you specifically.

Comment: Imgur is invisible to almost everyone in the country. @Deusovi

Comment: @Scratch---Cat Sounds like you're in China, or some other country with a firewall? There are likely a number of ways to get around that type of firewall. But that is something that we as a site cannot fix.

Comment: I'm in China. It looks like Imgur is also banned in Indonesia. By the way, please show me the link to joining The Sphinx's Lair so I can see if I can access the chatroom.